# Regge Theory references and predictive power

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, quantum-chromodynamics

I am considering studying Regge theory and would like to listen/read some introductory lectures, reviews or textbooks. Does anyone has any good material for beginners in Regge theory.

Furthermore I was wondering what is the state of the art of Regge theory nowadays. Does Regge theory give predictive results for soft hadron-hadron interactions or similar cases? I know that Regge theory is useful in (soft) diffraction in QCD, but does it provide actual predictive power or does it require some kind of matching to make predictions?

Due to its use in soft QCD I would guess that Regge Theory can also deal with non-perturbative effects or am I mistaken here? If yes can Regge theory give some guidelines of Hadronisation model building?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an introductory section on non-relativistic Regge theory in

- Landau and Lifshitz, Quantum Mechanics, 3rd Edition, Section 141.

You will also find discussions in old particle physics books such as

- Gasiorowicz, "Elementary Particle Physics"

Two general first principles overviews covering the non-relativistic case and it's proposed extension to the relativistic case are

- Froissart, "Mandelstam Theory and Regge Poles: An Introduction for Experimentalists"
- Frautschi, "Regge Poles and S-Matrix Theory"

One of the unfortunately few books to introduce Regge Theory and the Veneziano amplitude (beginning of string theory) from first principles is

- Muirhead, Notes on Elementary Particles

This set of notes

- Hiscox, "Analysis of Regge poles in non-relativistic
  quantum mechanics", [link](https://orca.cardiff.ac.uk/54238/1/U574346.pdf)

is a good introduction and contains many more references which are less elementary. A modern perspective is summarized by the article linked in the [comments](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02456).